# Migration from Jboss5.1 to Jboss 7.x

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x, jboss6.x

Right now I am using Jboss 5.1 (with jdk 1.6), According to our project we are using some property files etc and all kept it in deploy folder and some other folder kept inside bin,client, common folder and so on, Now in Jboss-7 complete diectory structure is changed some folders availabe in 5 are nor present in 7, Anybody have experience on such migration? (required jdk is 1.8) below one is difference between 7 and 5

[image]

Some extra files are present in particular folders as shown below in my project, (bin, client, common,common-lib-bckup,jbossws-cxf-bin-dist,lib,server) so my query is where to keep these files in jboss7 as some folder structure is not available.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWOef.png)

[image]

below one is server folder structure
[image]

Comment: I'm working on a migration from 5 to 7. What is your question?

Comment: please let me know, the folder structure I need to take care in jboss-7, during configuration/deployment, as the directory structure is different in jboss-5....

Comment: I don't know what your needs are, but I have found the modules very handy.

Comment: Please provide info regarding keeping files in respective modules

Comment: obviously, the wars must go in deployments, how do you load the .properties?

Comment: private Properties loadConfigurationFromClasspath() {
  ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();

Comment: OK: I have made a jar with my config files, and I have put the jar in a module that I add in the dependencies wherever I need it.